# CASE types character varying and boolean cannot be matched

Tags: sql

The code I wrote is

```
case 
    when employee_today = employee_today THEN employee_today
    when employee_today = null THEN employee_today = employee_yesterday
        else 'Null'
        END AS source,
count(*) AS total_count
```

I've tried the ::varchar but it does not seem to want to cooperate, any suggestions?

Comment: Could not get exactly what you are trying to do or what is the pinpoint problem you're trying to solve, personally.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Your (incorrect) expression boils down to: "SELECT employee_today, COUNT(*) AS total_count FROM myTable GROUP BY employee_today".

Comment: Sorry was trying to replace the null values in the employee today with the null values in employee yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
case 
    when employee_today = 'employee_today' THEN employee_today
    when employee_today is null THEN 'employee_yesterday'
        else 'Null'
        END AS source,
count(*) AS total_count
```

if this does not work let me know , i will modify accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

So I was trying to replace the null values with the employee_yesterday values when the Employee_today came out as null.

This I was actually able to achieve by doing

```
COALESCE(employee_today, employee_yesterday, 'Employee Unknown') source,
```

So this allowed me to replace all the null values in employee_today with the values in employee_yesterday and if they both came out null, the instead of nothing filling it I replace it with 'Employee Unknown'

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
source =
case 
    when employee_today is null THEN employee_yesterday
    else employee_today 
END,
count(*) AS total_count
```

There were a few things wrong with your statement:

```
case 
    --this would always be true unless it was NULL
    when employee_today = employee_today THEN employee_today 
    -- NULL != NULL, you need to use IS NULL unless NULL is a text value and then it
    --should be quoted with = 'NULL'. Also, this isn't how you set the value to the column
    when employee_today = null THEN employee_today = employee_yesterday
        --else NULL is automatic in CASE expressions, but here you are setting it to the string 'NULL' 
        --which may or may not be intended... usually it is not
        else 'Null'
        END AS source,
count(*) AS total_count
```